# Using an existing DIV as popup? (pure CSS or JS needed?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a page consisting of a sidebar and main content area. The sidebar has several `<div>`s with unique ids containing images, formulars, and other explainations that are ment to help the user unserstand the text of the main content.

```
<aside>
    <div id="expl1" class="explaination">
        latin for "I think, therefore I am"
    </div>
    <div id="expl2" class="explaination">
        <img src="images/bellcurve.png"> Bell Curve.
    </div>
</aside>
<main>
    <p>
        some text.
    </p>
    <p>
        some more text <span class="hint explain1"> with explaination available</span> in the sidebar.
    </p>
    <p>
        even more text user <span class="hint explain2">can hover over</span> for information.
    </p>
</main>
```

Is there a way to "copy/move" the relevant explaination div (the whole thing is a flexbox layout, no floats) so it appears next to the marked area in the main text? Ideally the popup box should be "toggled" on/off by clicking on the marked text and while active, the popup box should scroll with the text - as if you had put a post-it note on the text.

Is this doable? And if it is doable, do you need JavaScript for it or can it work with only pure HTML/CSS?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/rdTkb/

Comment: thank you, that didn't solve my problem yet, but it gave me a good point to start digging a bit deeper. The problems that remain are: 1.) can you realiably position the popup right next to the text element that is used to toggle the popup (or do you need some JS to get the text's position and adjust the popup's class top/left values accordingly)? 2.) can you "clone" the explaination div, so that the "original" stays in the sidebar while the popup appears in the main content div? (I guess the second one will require JS because it's DOM manipulation)